# Latex Table font size set to 10pt

Tags: fontsize

I would like to set my table to font 10pt. Here is my coding

```
     \begin{table}[h]
     \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
     \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
     \hline
                     & A   & B      & C  & D         \\ \hline
     Type  & Online  & Online & Online & Online      \\ \hline
     Programming Language     & Javascript  & PHP    & Javascript & Javascript, PHP, Jquery \\ \hline
     Multiple Choice Exercise & No  & No     & Yes        & Yes                     \\ \hline
     Studies Material         & Notes, exercise, flash card and video. & Video  &            &                         \\ \hline
     Downloadable Notes       &                                        &        &            &                         \\ \hline
     Advantages               &                                        &        &            &                         \\ \hline
     Disadvantages            &                                        &        &            &                         \\ \hline
```

\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

Comment: by default it will be 10pt, so if it isn't you need to show what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10pt is still too large for your table, and making it much smaller will make it unreadable. So, I suggest using a different tabular environment; the `tabulary`, which can automatically take care of line rapping. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\small 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*5{L}@{}}
    \toprule
    & A     & B      & C   & D    \\ \midrule
    Type  & Online  & Online & Online   & Online  \\ \midrule
    Programming Language     & Javascript & PHP  & Javascript  & Javascript, PHP, Jquery \\\midrule
    Multiple Choice Exercise & No  & No   & Yes & Yes \\ \midrule
    Studies Material         & Notes, exercise, flash card and video. & Video  & Free access to notes and e-book & Receiving news update notes, exercise and quizzes. \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]